# Set focus on kendoui multiselect

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

How can I set the focus to my kendoui multiselect element, after view init (ngAfterViewInit)?.

At normal input elements I set the focus like:

HTML:

```
<input #setFocus type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="code" id="code" />
```

Component:

```
@ViewChild('setFocus') focusElement: any;
...
ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.focusElement) {
        this.focusElement.nativeElement.focus();
    }
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: An improvement in the focus|blur support is planned - https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/335
.Until it is implemented, you will need to use some of the given suggestions in this thread.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will wait for the focus/blur support.

Answer (score 1):

I used this for AutoComplete, maybe it can help:

Template:

```
<kendo-autocomplete #customerIdCtl ...
```

Component:

```
@ViewChild('customerIdCtl') customerIdCtl


ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const el: any = document.querySelectorAll(`#${this.customerIdCtl.focusableId}`)[0]
      el.focus()
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at their [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/api/MultiSelectComponent/#toc-open), you can use the `open` input

```
@Component({
    selector: 'tester',
    template: `
        <kendo-multiselect #setFocus [data]="items"></kendo-multiselect>
    `
})
class TesterComponent {

   @ViewChild('setFocus') 
   focusElement: MultiSelectComponent;

   ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.focusElement.open = true;
   }   
}
```

You can toggle this for instance, by using `[open]` as template input.

Answer (score 0):

You can always look at html how control is rendered and you can use.

```
let el = this.focusElement.nativeElement;

if (el.className.indexOf("k-multiselect") != -1) { // kendo multiselect
  el.children[0].children[1].children[0].focus();
}
```

or with jquery

```
let el = this.focusElement.nativeElement;
$(el).find(".k-input").focus();
```

until Kendo implements this properly.